# how to add Authorization token to retrofit header using hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to add AUTH Token to Retrofit
I'm saving token on preferences Datastore
but when I trying to retrieve it show null

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8Hk0.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My code like this and its working.

```
    private fun getHeaderInterceptor():Interceptor{
    return Interceptor { chain ->
        val request =
            chain.request().newBuilder()
                .header("Cookie", cookie!!)
                .build()
        chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```

Full code: https://gist.github.com/Cr3bain/adf61caaa9da3291e1739c9bf0f334d8